# What is the meaning of ({})?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6

Sometime I use JavaScript or MongoDB, 
I can see the code like this: `({})`

For instance in this line of code:

```
db.users.find({})
```

But I don't know what exactly means.
Will you tell me what that is?

Comment: Do you have some context? Do you have an example line where it is used?

Comment: for example, db.users.find({}) in mongodb. I used it db.users.find() but it works! so my question is, why they need {}?

Comment: It means to fetch everything without a filter

Answer (score 5):

`{}` is an empty object initializer (aka "object literal). It creates an object with no properties of its own. The reason it's in `()` is probably that it appears where otherwise a `{` would indicate the start of a block.

Re your edit adding an example:

```
db.users.find({})
```

That creates a blank object (`{}`) and then calls `db.users.find` with that object as an argument. See [dvlgs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054174/157247) for what that means to MongoDB.

Comment: Lovely! in other words, it means function with empty object, right?

Comment: @Jay - Not necessarily. In `foo({})`, it means "create a blank object and then call `foo` with that object as an argument." But in `a = Array.from({length:10}, () => ({}));` it means "when the `Array.from` callback is called, create and return an empty object."

Comment: hi @T.J. Crowder +1 .A function expression and a function declaration are not considered a block (like a `{}` of an `if`, `while`, etc), righ?, or is the `function expression` considered a block?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - We've already had this discussion, haven't we? See https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-function-definitions and https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-block. Function bodies have many similarities with blocks, but they're *part of* the function definition, not a block attached to the function definition.

Comment: No@- T.J. Crowder, we are talking only about function declarations only, not function expressions, but thanks, I needed to confirm that and now it is clear to me

Answer (score 2):

In what context?

`db.collection.find({})`, for example, means "list documents without any filters".

Answer (score 2):

About the particular case of mongoose and `.find` method

```
db.users.find({})
```

means to find all the data in the collection `users` and returns it *(be careful db.users.find will returns a `Promise` object that needs to be resolved)*.

`db.users.find({})` is equivalent to `SELECT * from users WHERE 1` if it was SQL.

`{}` means that we call the function `db.users.find({})` with default condition *(first argument of find is the condition aka the where of the request)*. By default the argument is that you retrieve all the data.

---

---

In a more general context there a multiple context you can encounter this syntax for

```js
// #1

// Instantiation of an object
const obj = {};

// Parenthesis can be added here, they have no effect whatsoever
// There are useless
const obj2 = ({});

// Note that this also work
const obj3 = (((({}))));

console.log('objects', obj, obj2, obj3);
```

---

```js
// #2

// argument on a function
function f(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

// Here we call the function 'f' and set as the first argument of the
// function an object having a key names 'a'
f({
  a: 'arg1',
});
```

Comment: I think the OP means it in the context of mongoose in node

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Thx I haven't understood that. I have added explanation in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you often wrap an object with parenthesis to force an arrow function to return an object.

```
(a,b)=>"abc"         // returns a string
(a,b)=>{}            // does NOT return an object
(a,b)=>{ return {} } // because outer brackets is the function body
(a,b)=>({})          // DOES return an object, because parenthesis
```